# Finding the "most modular" subset of graph vertices, i.e. that minimize disagreement inside and outside

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard, clustering

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph.  I want to find the subset of vertices of $G$ that minimizes a certain modularity cost.  In our setting, the *modularity cost* of a subset $X$ is defined as the number of non-edges within $X$ plus the number of edges from $X$ to the outside, all this divided by $|X|$.  Intuitively, it is the number of edges to add/delete so that $X$ becomes an isolated clique, divided by $|X|$.

To put it formally, for $X, Y \subseteq V$, possibly overlapping, denote

$$E(X, Y) = \{\{u,v\} : u \in X, v \in Y, uv \in E\}$$

Also denote 
$$\overline{E(X, Y)} = \{\{u,v\} : u \in X, v \in Y, u \neq y, uv \notin E\}$$

I would like to find the subset $X \subseteq V(G)$ that minimizes

$$
\frac{|E(X, V \setminus X)| + |\overline{E(X, X)}|}{|X|}
$$

Is there anything in the literature about this?  I'd like to know if it's NP-hard, approximable, etc.

This relates to the densest subgraph problem, which can be found in polynomial time.  But densest subgraph ignores the outside edges.  Densest subgraph exploits a supermodular formulation, which does not apply here.There are also some (actually lots) of community detection papers out there, but I haven't found one that deals with this particular cost.

Comment: Interesting question!  The _divide by $|X|$_ makes it slightly unusual for me.  I don't know anything, but I was immediately reminded of a concept called _Integrity_, or _vulnerability measures_.  I'm not sure it's going to help you, but you can look in the literature, e.g. [A Survey of Integrity](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(92)90122-Q) for things that might be related.  Other concepts are _toughness_ and _covering number_.  _Integrity_ is also sometimes referred to as _Component Order Connectivity_, eg _A survey of component order connectivity models..._ by Gross et al